# how to affect on an element inside element html

Tags: html, css, hover

i am trying to make affect of the visibility of an span on hover
when i hover over the img the sqaure must be visible

```
<div class="headar_top">
        <a href=""><img id="timg"src="images/user.png"/></a>
        <a href="#sitemap"><img id="timg"src="images/sitemap.png"/></a>
        <span id="Square">
            <a href=""><button type="button" class="SquareButt">Log In</button></a>
            <a href=""><button type="button" class="SquareButt">Sign Up</button></a>
        </span>
    </div>

#timg:hover > #Square{
    visibility:visible;
}
#Square{
    margin-top:50px;
    height:80px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#f3f603;
    float:right;
    margin-right:-145px;
    visibility:hidden;

}
```

but still i can not make the changes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#square` is not a child of `#timg`, thus the direct children selector `>` can't work as you might expect: move instead the `id` to the parent link

```
<a href="" id="timg"><img src="images/user.png"/></a>
<a href="#sitemap"><img id="timg"src="images/sitemap.png"/></a>
<span id="Square">
   <button type="button" class="SquareButt">Log In</button> 
   <button type="button" class="SquareButt">Sign Up</button> 
</span>
```

and change the style like so

```
#timg:hover ~ #Square { ... }
```

Note: a button element can't be enclosed into a link

Comment: when i hover over the span  it  disappear , how to fix it so i can click on the button ?

Comment: in pure css you should enclose the button block in the element you're hovering, otherwise use js

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `#timg:hover ~ #Square { ... }`

Checkout this.

```css
#timg:hover ~#Square {
    display:block;
}
#Square{
    margin-top:50px;
    height:80px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#f3f603;
    float:right;
    margin-right:145px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="timg"><img src="images/user.png"/></a>
<a href="#sitemap"><img id="timg"src="images/sitemap.png"/></a>
<span id="Square">
   <button type="button" class="SquareButt">Log In</button> 
   <button type="button" class="SquareButt">Sign Up</button> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.container span {
       display:none;
   }

.container:hover span {
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img id="timg"src="images/user.png"/>
    <span>
 <a href=""><button type="button" class="SquareButt">Log In</button></a>
            <a href=""><button type="button" class="SquareButt">Sign Up</button></a>
</span>
</div>
```

Please use this code, working perfectly.